# Get image URL from wordpress WP-REST APi

Tags: android, json, wordpress, rest, android-volley

I'm facing an issue regarding getting images from wordpress using

> WP-Rest-API

This is the `JSON` Structure of wordpress

```
> [{"id":2107,"date":"2017-09-28T07:32:09","date_gmt":"2017-09-28T07:32:09","guid":{"rendered":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/?p=2107"},"modified":"2017-09-28T07:32:09","modified_gmt":"2017-09-28T07:32:09","slug":"flute-test","status":"publish","type":"post","link":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/2017\/09\/28\/flute-test\/","title":{"rendered":"Flute
> Test"},"content":{"rendered":"<figure id=\"attachment_2108\"
> style=\"width: 300px\" class=\"wp-caption alignnone\"><img
> class=\"size-medium wp-image-2108\"
> src=\"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd-300x210.jpg\" alt=\"error\" width=\"300\" height=\"210\"
> srcset=\"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd-300x210.jpg
> 300w,
> http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd-768x538.jpg
> 768w,
> http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd-1024x717.jpg
> 1024w,
> http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd-545x382.jpg
> 545w,
> http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd.jpg
> 1068w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px\" \/>
```

`ImageURL` is in html `img` tag. how can i get that?

Answer (score -1):

I think its late but maybe it could help some one
I use these codes for getting picture:

for get image url you should have basic knowlege of JsonObject and jsonArray I change my Answer base of last wordpress Json Another Alternative could be using Gson library.

```
     import org.json.JSONArray;
     import org.json.JSONException;
     import org.json.JSONObject;

     List <myImageHolderObject> list ;

     public void ImageListMaker(String js){

       try{

      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(js);  //get ASrray of items
      int  Jlength = jArray.length();
      for (int i = 0; i < Jlength; i++) {   //loop throw evry item and get image url

      JSONObject jo = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

      int id = jo.getInt("id");
      JSONObject c =jo.getJSONObject("media_details").getJSONObject("sizes");

      String thumb = c.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("source_url");
      String medium = c.getJSONObject("medium").getString("source_url");
      String full = c.getJSONObject("full").getString("source_url");
      list.add(new myImageHolderObject(id,thumb,medium,full));

     }
     }catch(JSONException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }


}
```

Comment: Please write an explanation for what your code snippet does so people reading your answer will know exactly what your snippet solves and in what way.